# minimization in entropy

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to calculate some minimization problems arising in entropy (with several variables). One typical case here is the fact that we deal with functions containing the forms $\lambda \log \lambda$, where $\lambda \ge 0$ with the convention that $0\log 0 =0$. I guess this is the reason the Minimize is not giving me any answer. My code is relatively simple which is

```
Minimize[{f,g==0&&h==0},{lambda1, lambda2}]
```

where I want to minimize $f$ subject to the equations $g=0$ and $h=0$, in terms of $\lambda$s. Is there a way to define the quantity $0\log 0 =0$ such that it does not enter in some unnecessary loop? Advanced thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: What is f &g? Maybe give an example will make the question easy to understand.

Comment: I would define a new function and define the value for x==0: myentropy[x_]:=x Log[x]; myentropy[0]=0;

Comment: Set `\[Lambda] > 0 ` as condition in `Minimize` and treat `\[Lambda] == 0 ` as special case. But be aware, Minimize doesn't always find solutions for transcedental functions.

Comment: @DanielHuber Something like `xLogx = Function[x, Piecewise[{{x Log[x], x > 0}}, 0]]` is probably more appropriate for symbolic manipulation.